# Broadcom BCM4312 driver for Ubuntu 14/15?

Tags: drivers, broadcom

Today in class we found that after installing Ubuntu, the Wi-Fi doesn't work. The Wi-Fi LED stays orange (Blue means it works).

- Where I can found the drivers?
- What should I do in the CLI when we have the drivers?

Ubuntu's are: 14.4, 14.10, 15.4 & 15.10 (All have versions of x86 & x64)
Laptop is HP 6735s

WLAN Device is Broadcom bcm4312 [14e4:4315]

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score -1):

- Insert your Ubuntu instalation media(usually the USB flash drive)
- Go to pool>main>d>dkms and copy the .deb file to a New Folder on your Desktop
- Then go to pool>restricted>b and copy the .deb file to the same folder as dkms file(previous step)
- Open a terminal and using `cd` command navigate to the New Folder
- Run `sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb` and `sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb` and done, your driver should work now or after a reboot.

Comment: The Broadcom proprietary driver *bcmwl-kernel-source* is not correct for his 14e4:4315 device.

Comment: I have the same driver and it works for me.